# Sends form from first field on iphone (Safari and Chrome) instead of last

Tags: html

I have a contact form with two fields, the first one with type email and the second text area.
On my iphone in Chrome and Safari it shows the blue OK button sending the form on the first field (email) instead of the Enter button just to fill in the field. 
So the form gets sent away (when clicking blue OK) before reaching the last field (the text area).
Why could this be happening?

```html
<span>Email</span>
<input id="Youremail" name="Emailfield" type="email"> 

<span>Message</span>
<textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="Message" id="Yourmessage"></textarea>
```

Comment: Are these fields inside one `<form>` element?

Comment: Yes, with method="post" and url in action=""

Comment: Please expand your snippet to include the actual form. It's hard to diagnose an issue we can't actually see.

Comment: <form method="post" action="https://www.url.com/" name="contactform">

<h2 id="contact">Heading</h2>

<p>
Some text...
</p>
 
<span>Email</span>
<input id="Youremail" name="Emailfield" type="email">
  
<span>Message</span>
<textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="Message" id="Yourmessage"></textarea>
  
<center>
<button name="Mybutton" id="Mybutton" type="submit"> 
Send
</button>
</center>

</form>